# When execute KNN on user based collaborative filter?

Tags: recommendation-engine, knn, collaborative-filtering

I have seen codes and examples of user based collaborative filter that executes knn before calculates similarities, and others that executes only after, it means, executes knn on similarities matrix.

So my doubt is when calculates KNN algorithm, on data matrix before calculates similarities, or on similarities matrix?

References:

> https://github.com/mhahsler/recommenderlab/blob/master/R/RECOM_UBCF.R
>
> Dietmar Jannach, Markus Zanker, Alexander Felfernig, Gerhard
>   Friedrich - Recommender Systems An Introduction - Cambridge University
>   Press (2010)
>
> A CUDA-enabled Parallel Implementation of Collaborative Filtering
>   Zhongya Wanga, Ying Liua, and Pengshan Ma

Comment: If KNN is used before actually calculating similarities, what is used to distinguish neighborhood? And in second case - if u using KNN, why having all similarities pre-calculated in a form of matrix? It's heavy :-) Do You not confused similarities with co-occurance?

Comment: Also it would be probably the best, if You could provide links to codes and examples that You are referring to.